# webservice returning 500 asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services

Got a very weird problem.

I just successfully implemented a simple ajax validation on my site (Yey!). I hooked up the validation to the OnFocusOut event of every textbox via backcode, which runs perfectly.

The weird bug happens when,on the same page , I call the exact same method and pass the same parameters via a validate() method or add the attribute OnFocusOut on document.ready() . I keep getting a status of 500.

I was able to verify that the server side method isn't successfully called when using validate() but runs when OnFocusOut is triggered.

WebServiceAdapter

```
function ValueChanged(target, validationDiv,valueType) {

targetControl = document.getElementById(validationDiv);
```

// Added this part because I'm guessting a null is causing it
    var str = (target.value === '') ? " " : target.value;

```
switch (valueType) {
    case "email":
        webServiceAdapter.EmailExist(str);
    break;
case "screenName":
    webServiceAdapter.ValidScreenName(str);
    break;
case "changePassword":
    webServiceAdapter.PasswordCorrect(str);
    break;
}
```

Adding OnFocusOut backcode - WORKS

```
 txtEmail.Attributes.Add("onfocusout", "ValueChanged(this,'"+Email.ClientID+"','email')");
```

Adding OnFocusOut jquery - DOES NOT WORK

```
$("#<%=txtEmail.ClientID%>").attr("onfocusout", "ValueChanged('<%=txtEmail.ClientID%>', '<%=Email.ClientID%>', 'email')");
```

Calling via validate() method - DOES NOT WORK

```
 ValueChanged('<%=txtEmail.ClientID%>', '<%=Email.ClientID%>', 'email');
```

**Edit:**

I'm also getting this error "An error occurred: Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'email'." After invoking validate()

Comment: Can you post the code for your Ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.

Quite embarrassing really. It was a "common sense bug".

ValueChanged() was expecting an object as the first parameter - this is what the backcode is doing by using "this". For the call from validate(), i was using the ID.